# Inner joins in php

Tags: php, sql, tags

```
SELECT thread.id AS p_id, post.title, post.content, author.username, author.id AS a_id
                         FROM thread INNER JOIN author
                         ON author_id = author.id
                         ORDER BY thread.created DESC
                         LIMIT $start, 30
```

I have a table called posts, posts_id and tags.

How can I extend the above SQL statement to get all the tags related to each post using INNER JOINS,...or something else?

Comment: Where's the 'post' table being defined in that query? YOu can't select "post.title' or "post.content" as it stands now, as there isn't a POST table/alias

Comment: I think he meant to write SELECT post, I've seen this query somewhere before, maybe its copied and pasted

Answer (score 2):

Try this(assumed the table with tag info to be tags and having a thread_id column):

```
SELECT thread.id AS p_id, 
             post.title, 
             post.content, 
             author.username, 
             author.id AS a_id,
             GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag_name ORDER BY tag_name DESC SEPARATOR ',') AS tags
 FROM thread INNER JOIN author
 ON author_id = author.id INNER JOING TAGS 
 ON thread.id = tags.thread_id
 GROUP BY thread.id
 ORDER BY thread.created DESC

 LIMIT $start, 30
```

EDIT: Moved GROUP By up one line.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT thread.id AS p_id, post.title, post.content, author.username, author.id AS a_id
 FROM thread 
 LEFT JOIN author ON author_id = author.id
 LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.thread_id =  thread.id
 ORDER BY thread.created DESC
 LIMIT $start, 30

Sanil

Comment: Isn't this just the same thing...?