# Getting all tags in php

Tags: mysql, tags

I have a similar table structure as this questions accepted answer: [Recommended SQL database design for tags or tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/how-do-you-recommend-implementing-tags-or-tagging)

Except mine is

```
thread, thread_tags and tags
```

Using the following SQL command I can get one tag associated with each thread, how can I get all the tags associated with each thread?

```
SELECT 
  thread.id AS t_id, 
  thread.title, 
  thread.content, 
  author.username, 
  author.id AS a_id
FROM thread 
INNER JOIN author
  ON author_id = author.id
INNER JOIN thread_tags
  ON thread_id = thread.id
INNER JOIN tags
  ON tag_id = tags.id       
ORDER BY thread.created DESC
```

Comment: Post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612353/inner-joins-in-php ???

Comment: what is `author_id`? you should put tablenames everywhere, or better yet, a shortened name (ie `FROM thread TH INNER JOIN author A on TH.author_id = A.id`

Answer (score 0):

I think your joins look fine, but you arent going to select anything from the `tags` table unless you put it there!  `T.*` below

```
SELECT TH.id, TH.title, TH.content, A.username, A.id, T.*                  
FROM thread TH
INNER JOIN author A ON TH.author_id = A.id 
INNER JOIN thread_tags TT ON TT.thread_id = TH.id 
INNER JOIN tags T ON TT.tag_id = T.id 
ORDER BY TH.created DESC
```

Comment: I still only get one tag, I want to get all the tags associated with each thread.

Comment: i dont see why, so lets strip to basics.  can you show some (10-20) rows of thread_tags?  `thread_tags` is a many-to-many with `tag.id` and `thread.id` pairs right?

Comment: try naming every table, lose the order by and the author.  see if u can join threads, thread_tags, and tags proper